# How to have "standard PAL" flag with a 1920x1080 video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mediainfo

I need to transcode some 1920x1080 video and to have the mediainfo flag "standard PAL" in it.

I tried many things with ffmpeg but either I have the PAL flag with 720x576 or it disappears with 1920x1080.

I know it is something I can do because some I have some video file with everithing in them
https://pastecode.xyz/view/ac09a472

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the video standard metadata to PAL:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_format=1 pal.mp4
```

Assuming video encoding is H.264 (AVC).

It doesn't make sense to mark 1920x1080 video as PAL, because PAL standard resolution is about 720x576 (not HD), but you can still set the metadata.

The metadata is described in a table in [ISO/IEC 14496-10](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-201610-S!!PDF-E&type=items) document:

> video_format indicates the representation of the pictures as specified in Table E-2, before being coded in accordance with
>   this Recommendation | International Standard. When the video_format syntax element is not present, video_format value
>   shall be inferred to be equal to 5.
>
> Table E-2 – Meaning of video_format
>   video_format Meaning
>   0 Component
>   1 PAL
>   2 NTSC
>   3 SECAM
>   4 MAC
>   5 Unspecified video format

The FFmpeg `h264_metadata` is documented in [FFmpeg Bitstream Filters Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-h264_005fmetadata)